# Как при наведении на один элемент менять стили другого элемента если элемент находится с верху?

Tags: css, hover

Не судите строго я начинающий.

И Русский у меня не лучший, заранее извиняюсь.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(22, 129, 129);
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.black_white {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.black:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

.black:hover~.white {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.white:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.white:hover~.black {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

.black_white {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.black {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 600%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.white {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 600%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="black_white d-flex">
  <div class="white d-flex">
    <p>Белый</p>
  </div>
  <div class="black d-flex">
    <p>Черный</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Основная проблема в том что .black:hover ~ .white работает, а .white:hover ~ .black не работает.

Я пробовал менять их местами и получалось на оборот что .white:hover ~ .black работает, а не работает .black:hover ~ .white работает.

Еще пробовал менять на "+", не получается*/

Comment: Саму верстку можно менять? Т.е. теги переставить можно?

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такой дикий вариант:

```
.black_white .white:has(+ .black:hover) {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

Информация: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант - через родителя...

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(22, 129, 129);
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.black_white {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.black:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

.black_white:has(.black:hover) .white {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.white:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.black_white:has(.white:hover) .black {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

.black_white {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.black {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 600%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.white {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 600%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="black_white d-flex">
  <div class="white d-flex">
    <p>Белый</p>
  </div>
  <div class="black d-flex">
    <p>Черный</p>
  </div>
</div>
```